1” XPS 3/4” plywood basement subfloor Wisconsin
I’m making a subfloor for my basement in Wisconsin.
The house was built in 2017, and would have had to pass all code requirements and inspections.
The basement has no moisture issues, and is always dry.
Is using 1” XPS, taped at joints and sealed at edges, with 3/4” plywood that are secured by tapcons code compliant?
I really don’t want to get this completed and then have an inspector tell me I have to tear it out. Thank you in advance.

Your local building inspector is usually the best person to ask.  They know all the local codes that differ from national.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].
